# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' while reloading table data

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use two lists for my app, one is used to save users I am following, and the other one is used to save my followers. Then I have a segmented control to select between the two lists and lastly I created an other list which is actually related to the UITableView, so I think it's so much easier this way.

The problem comes when I actually change from one list to another:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    let user = tableList[indexPath.row]
    cell.userUser.text = user.userName

    return cell
}

@IBAction func switchValue(_ sender: Any) {
    section = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

    switch section {
    case 0:
        showFollowers()
    case 1:
        showFollowing()
    default:
        return
    }
}

func showFollowers () {
    tableList.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()

    if !followersList.isEmpty {
        for users in followersList {
            tableList.append(users)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: tableList.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}

func showFollowing (){
    tableList.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()

    if !followingList.isEmpty {
        for users in followingList {
            tableList.append(users)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: tableList.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
* Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3901.4.2/UITableView.m:2071
* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'
```

I saw "UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext", I don't know what does that means but it says animation so I thought if I simplify the code it might work:

```
func showFollowers () {
    tableList = followersList
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func showFollowing (){
    tableList = followingList
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

What did I get? The same error. Can somebody help me?

## NOTE

While debugging the app and figuring out where is actually the problem, I found that the problem appears only if I change between the lists very quickly. For real, I'm not joking. If I press the button slowly, it works completely fine.

Comment: Slowly I mean that I press the button, then I wait 2-3 seconds and I press it again.

Comment: I don't see how your second piece of code (which is the correct approach by the way) can cause the same exception since it isn't calling `deleteRows`. Do you call that function anywhere else in your code?  You don't call insert/delete if you are simply reloading.

Comment: Also, please show your `numberOfRows(in section:)` code

Comment: @Paulw11 First of all, thank you for your suggestion. I wanted to use the first code because of the animation, but if you say that the second one is better I'll use it. On the second hand, it throws the same error: "(...) reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'".

Comment: @Paulw11 I also added in the question the function you asked for.

Comment: Can you share your entire view controller as a gist? You must be manipulating the arrays or the tableview somehow - Here is a simple test I created and I can switch the segmented control as fast as I can without issue - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/82c4b05310e4edac98db1345f18cfbfe

Comment: Yes of course. I've started a new file step by step to see where is the problem. I found out that the issue is in the function setUserImage(url : URL, indexPath at : IndexPath, key : String). I'm using that function to save all user images so I don't have to download them every time I change the segmented control. How can I fix this?